# Why I got error: `error while loading shared libraries: libmpich.so.3`?

Tags: software-installation, path, libraries, version, mpi

I installed mpich-3.0.4 not in a default location. I installed it based on the [mpich installer's guidance](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.0.4/mpich-3.0.4-installguide.pdf).

However when I try to run:

```
mpiexec -n 4 -f machinefile ./mpich-3.0.4/examples/cpi
```

It gives me an error, which is:

```
./mpitrial/official_examples/cpi: error while loading shared libraries: libmpich.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I had set PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But is still gives me that error.

Finally I just typed:

```
sudo apt-get install mpich2
```

Afterwards, I can run the `mpiexec` without error.

Why did this happen?

Comment: When you say `which mpiexec`, does it give the correct path (the path to your custom 3.0.4 installation)?

Comment: @WesleyBland Yes, Sir. I also type `which mpicc`, `which mpif90`, etc. But thanks for make some diagnose

Comment: And just to be sure, if you `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the first directory is wherever your `<mpich-dir>/lib` is located?

Comment: @WesleyBland It will give: `/mirror/mpich-3/lib:` And my instalation directory for mpi is `/mirror/mpich-3/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are installing mpich 3 from source, you need to provide `--enable-shared` option while configuring in order to create an `so`, which is shared library. See section 2.6 of the guide you linked. An example from my `config.log`:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/kcm92/mpich3-install --enable-shared
make && make install
```

Comment: OK I did not read that Section. Thank you @Ketan